# Copy "X" rows of Data

Tags: excel, vba

I need to build a macro that allows me to copy a range of data to the clipboard but that data is stored in a daily changing number of rows. To clarify, I have two tabs on this blank worksheet that I fill out every day. Tab 1 is called "Recap", and based on what I type into the "Recap" tab I have data pulling into my second tab called "Exception Log" through "if" formulas. The data pulls into A8 through F8 and Column E is blank so that if I copy A8:F8 it matches the formatting in another spreadsheet where I will paste the data. Some days there are only 3 rows of data meaning I want A8:F10 copied into the clipboard but other days there is 30 rows of data meaning I want A8:F37 copied into the clipboard. In an attempt to try to make this a little easier I added a basic count formula to Cell H5 that counts the number of rows with data in them and therefore the number of rows that I want copied from columns A to F starting at row 8 but I can't figure out how to work it into a Macro. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Example : To copy from a range in sheet1 to another range in sheet2 starting at C6 :

```
Range("A8:F13").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Feuil2").Range("C6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

if your row number is H5 :

```
n=range("H5").value
Range("A8:F" & n).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Feuil2").Range("C6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```